# Backend Validation error message using django

Tags: django-models, django-templates, django-views

While Giving Correct username and password in login page its working correctly,while giving wrong username and password,how to show the error message.

views.py

```
def user_login(request):
   logout(request)
   username = password = ''
   username = request.POST.get('username')
   print(username)
   password = request.POST.get('password')
   print(password)
   if request.POST:
       user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
       if user is not None:
               if user.is_active:
                       auth_login(request, user)
                       return render(request, 'admin_pannel.html', { 'dept' : dt, 'ds' : ds })
                       return redirect('/dashboard/')
   return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'dt' : dt })
```

Answer (score 0):

Error messages are usually handled by an instance of [`django.forms.forms.Form`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L495). For your view I would suggest something like this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        logout(request)
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            auth_login(request, user)
            return render(request, 'admin_pannel.html', {...})
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()

    return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'form': form, ...})
```

A quick glance at [`AuthenticationForm.clean`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L198) looks like it will accomplish the same thing that you are doing in your view.

The only other thing that comes to mind is [Django's messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/messages/), but I don't think that would be your best option.